# NullPointerException on EditText .getText().toString()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I'm getting a nullPointerException on "textTo.getText().toString();" below. I don't understand why. I've tried placing the EditText's findViewById's inside onClick too, but no difference.

Maila.Java:

```
public class Maila extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

    public static Maila newInstance() {
        Maila f = new Maila();
System.out.println("Initialiserad");        
        return f;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_form, container, false);

         return v;
    }

    Button buttonSend;
    EditText textTo;
    EditText textSubject;
    EditText textMessage;
    EditText textName;
    EditText textTel; 
    EditText textFrom;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated (View v, Bundle SavedInstanceState){
        buttonSend = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.mailKnapp);
        textTo = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.string.mailAdress);
        textSubject = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editTextMeddelandeTitel);
        textName = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editTextNamn);
        textTel = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editTextTel);
        textMessage = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editTextMeddelande);
        textFrom = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editTextEpost);
        Button mailKnapp = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.mailKnapp);
        mailKnapp.setOnClickListener(this);

         }



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
 String to = textTo.getText().toString();
System.out.println("textTo: " + to);          
          String subject = textSubject.getText().toString();
System.out.println("textSubject: " + subject);
          String message = textMessage.getText().toString();
System.out.println("textMessage: " + message);
          String namn = textName.getText().toString();
System.out.println("textName: " + namn);          
          String telefon = textTel.getText().toString();
System.out.println("textTel: " + telefon);        

            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});
          //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{ to});
          //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{to});
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, ("Skickat från TestApp FöretagsInfo: " + subject));
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ("Från: " + namn + ", " + textFrom + "\nTelefon: " + telefon + "\nMeddelande:\n" + message));

          //need this to prompts email client only
          email.setType("message/rfc822");



          try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Skicka med: "));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException exception) {
                Toast.makeText(Maila.this.getActivity(), "Ingen E- postklient kunde hittas på enheten!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
}
}
```

LogCat:

```
    01-17 21:58:26.576: D/AndroidRuntime(21589): Shutting down VM
01-17 21:58:26.581: W/dalvikvm(21589): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x413462a0)
01-17 21:58:26.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21589): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 21:58:26.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21589): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 21:58:26.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21589):    at nu.sluggo.testapp.foretagsinfo.Maila.onClick(Maila.java:64)
01-17 21:58:26.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21589):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4232)
01-17 21:58:26.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21589):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17298)
01-17 21:58:26.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21589):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-17 21:58:26.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21589):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-17 21:58:26.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21589):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 21:58:26.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
01-17 21:58:26.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21589):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 21:58:26.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21589):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 21:58:26.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21589):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
01-17 21:58:26.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21589):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
01-17 21:58:26.606: E/AndroidRuntime(21589):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 22:03:35.716: I/Process(21589): Sending signal. PID: 21589 SIG: 9
```

contact_form.XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/BGColor"  >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/BGColor" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mailTitel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mailTitel"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mailTitel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mailVarning"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mailVarning"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mailVarning" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mailInfo"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mailInfo"
        android:textColor="@color/mailInfo"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mailInfo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNamn"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/boxboarder"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/editTextNamn"
        android:textColorHint="@color/editTextHint"
        android:textSize="@dimen/editText_textSize"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textCapWords" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTel"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/boxboarder"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" 
        android:hint="@string/editTextTel" 
        android:textColorHint="@color/editTextHint"
        android:textSize="@dimen/editText_textSize"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextEpost"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/boxboarder"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" 
        android:hint="@string/editTextEpost" 
        android:textColorHint="@color/editTextHint"
        android:textSize="@dimen/editText_textSize"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextMeddelandeTitel"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/boxboarder"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:hint="@string/editTextMeddelandeTitel" 
        android:textColorHint="@color/editTextHint"
        android:textSize="@dimen/editText_textSize"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextMeddelande"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/boxboarder"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences" 
        android:hint="@string/editTextMeddelande" 
        android:textColorHint="@color/editTextHint"
        android:textSize="@dimen/editText_textSize"
        android:minLines="4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mailKnapp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="skickaMail"
        android:text="@string/skickaKnapp" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

(strings.XML:)

```
...
<string name="mailAdress">test@sluggotech.se</string>
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because:

```
textTo = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.string.mailAdress);
```

You have no `EditText` by that name, so it returns `null`.

I *suspect* you meant to use `R.id.mailInfo`

**Edit to add:** It appears there's multiple issues here, that would be one.

Another is that you're not using the `View` passed into `onViewCreated()`. All of those calls should be:

```
v.findViewById(...);
```

But that's unlikely to work since I don't see layout named `contact_form` anywhere.

Comment: and it should be R.id not R.string

Comment: This string is a reference to: <string name="mailAdress">my@emailaddress.com</string>, so it shoudn't be a problem, right?

Comment: Added that to the description too

Comment: Erm, that's a string. You can't magically make that into an `EditText`

Comment: ...But Maybe that's the issue? The String is not an EditText as I've stated, but a string. -But if I chande EditText to String, I get "Cannot cast from View to String". Tried changing getView to getResources() or getText(), but it didn't work either

Comment: because ... it's not a `View` either.

Comment: Changed to textTo = getResources().getString(R.string.mailAdress); Works! Thanx Brian!

Answer (score 0):

Inside OnCreateView method make v global variable like,

```
         View v=null;

       @Override
             public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                   v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_form, container, false);

                 return v;
             }
```

then use this v instead of getView

```
         buttonSend = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.mailKnapp);
```